# How to ignore the already logged in LinkedIn user when using Sign In with LinkedIn?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I have the sign-in with linkedin functionality working on my asp.net mvc site.

I noticed that when a user is already logged in to LinkedIn in the current browser that when I click the button to sign in with linkedin on my site that it automatically signs in to my site with the user that was already logged in instead of asking for a LinkedIn username and password.

Is there any way to ignore any already logged in users and ask for the username and password EVERY time someone hits the button to sign in with linkedin?  I don't want anyone to be surprised about who they get logged in as... as I was when I accidentally added the wrong LinkedIn login to my account on my site because of this.